# before after css doesnt work if we have some element in between

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

```
<input type="checkbox" name="NotifyWhenOpen" value="true">
<input type="hidden" name="NotifyWhenOpen" value="false">
<label for="NotifyWhenOpen">&nbsp;</label>
```

Above html doesnt work while below works

```
<input type="checkbox" name="NotifyWhenOpen" value="true">
<label for="NotifyWhenOpen">&nbsp;</label>
<input type="hidden" name="NotifyWhenOpen" value="false">
```

CSS:

```
.checkbox { position: relative; margin-top: 2px; padding: 0; display: inline-block }
.checkbox input[type=checkbox] { display: none; padding-left: 0; }  
.checkbox label:before { border-radius: 3px;  content: ""; display: inline-block; width: 16px; height: 16px; margin-right: 10px; position: absolute; left: 0; bottom: 1px; background: #eef5f7; border: 1px solid #999; } 
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before { content: "\2713"; font-size: 13px; color: #0090D9; text-align: center; font-weight: 600; line-height: 15px; }
```

Js Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x8VGB/

How to make it work with first one also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example your `label` element is not an adjacent sibling of your `checkbox` input (an hidden input is in the middle): so you need to use the general sibling selector `~` to target a not-adjacent sibling

```
input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label:before
```

---

See [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) for further detail and browser support

Comment: Thanx, it works. Could you please tell me where can i get the documentation for this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use another

Use ~ instead of +

Comment: It's been already answered and explained but +1 for your effort.